# IOS - Can crossing a geo-fence ping gps chip?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, geofencing, wakeup

I wonder, if it is possible to get a gps based location based on crossing a geo-fence. 
The workflow would be: 
When device is outside geo-fence, no locating is done.
When device crosses geo-fence, it locates (with best accuracy) via gps and sends location to server.

I heard, that this is not possible, but this sounds strange to me, since geo-fencing can be used to wake an app. So I don´t really get, why it should not be possible to wake app, in order to ping gps.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Yes, this is fairly easy to do. Have you looked at any documentation for CoreLocation?  You need to look into region monitoring and core,location background mode.

Comment: Hi Paul, 
thanks for the quick answer. I have to admit, that both me and my developer are very beginners. To us it looks like we can not combine gps and geo-fencing: All apps we found seem to use only geo-fencing. But in our case gps should be used to locate more accurate, as soon as user has entered geo-fence.

Comment: Geofencing is driven by GPS - You set up a CLCircularRegion and call `startMonitoringForRegion` on a CLLocationManager instance.  When the region is entered you get a call to `didEnterRegion` - In this method you can call `startUpdatingLocation` on the CLLocationManager instance to get location updates and stop location updates once you have the location.  If you are targeting ios9 it is even easier because there is a new `requestLocation` method that handles the start/stop for you.

Comment: Thanks! I hope, you have enough patience with me, cause I´m slow in getting the workflow of ios geo-fencing: 
If geofencing is using GPS, in which time interval is ios using the gps chip to check for crossing geo-fence?
Is this a fix value set by apple? Or can that be defined in app? I´m asking, cause my info is, that you can not define a time interval, when to ping the gps chip. 
My original goal was, to make the app check every 60 minutes, if user is inside a geo-fence. When inside, track based on distance filter (ping gps all 10 meters). When outside: Only check every 60min., if inside.

Comment: Nope, you just set a region to be monitored and get a callback once you are inside the region (or exit the region)

Comment: I guess your "nope" is related to setting an interval, when to check, if user is inside. Do you have any information, how often ios is checking this?
To my understanding ios is turning on gps -> checking position in or outside based on gps-coordinate -> creates the callback. But does that happen, every 5 min., every 15 min., every hour?

Comment: I have no idea. I have an app that uses region monitoring for regions that have a radius of about 200m. My app gets notified within about 30 seconds of arriving in the region, so I think iOS is checking almost continuously. Have you (or your developer) set up a test app?  It would take about 10-15 minutes to create a test app that monitors a region and then you can see for yourself that it region detection happens pretty quickly. Although getting an accurate location can be pretty slow in computer terms, it is typically a few to maybe 15 seconds